# StructureMap Custom ActionFilter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, structuremap

I am using Asp.Net MVC. I have custom AcitonFilter using structuremap.

In custom ActionFilter I use an enum type.

```
public enum TimeUnit
{
    Minute = 60,
    Hour = 3600,
    Day = 86400
}
```

And my ActionFilter class is:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class CustomAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public TimeUnit Time { get; set; }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var seconds = Convert.ToInt32(Time);

    }
}
```

And my structuremap's settings for ActionFilter is:

```
public class StructurMapFilterProvider : FilterAttributeFilterProvider
{
    private readonly Func<StructureMap.IContainer> _Container;

    public StructurMapFilterProvider(Func<StructureMap.IContainer> container)
    {
        _Container = container;
    }

    public override IEnumerable<Filter> GetFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext,
        ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
    {
        var filters = base.GetFilters(controllerContext, actionDescriptor);

        var container = _Container();

       foreach (var filter in filters)
        {
            container.BuildUp(filter.Instance);

            yield return filter;
        }
    }
}
```

After I use ActionFilter in action throw an Exception in

> container.BuildUp(filter.Instance);

Message of Exception is:

> Setter Property 'Time' (ActionFilters.TimeUnit): Required primitive dependency is not explicitly defined

I used like this:

```
[Custom(Time = TimeUnit.Hour)]
    public ActionResult MyAction(ViewModel model)
    {
        // my code
    }
```

What should I do?
How explicitly define a enumeration?

Comment: I think the problem you are not setting the Time property. Could you share the usage of that filter?

Comment: And the usage of "StructurMapFilterProvider"?

Comment: Try adding `[SetterProperty]` attribute on top of `Time` property. It should declared explicitly using the given attribute.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I had problem in usage of StrucMapFilterProvider. I filtered PrimitiveTypes there.

Comment: I see that the PrimitiveTypes filter can be overriden using `ObjectFactory.BuildUp` instead of `container.BuildUp`. It related with nested container where child container should be filled with policies, see https://github.com/structuremap/structuremap/issues/242.